# Either 'success' xor 'error' will be called in jQuery's ajax, right?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have to set a flag inside of `$.ajax()` and I would like to know if I have `success` and `error` so the execution will go into one of these functions all the time. Is that true? So there's no scenario when none of these functions are executed, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So there's no scenario when none of these functions are executed, right?

Assuming JavaScript keeps running on the page at all, you're guaranteed to get the `success` or `error` callback. Either way, you're guaranteed to get the `complete` callback.